# Winforms - discard unwanted double click

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click

In my C# Winforms application I have a 'Welcome' window with a number of buttons. One of these is 'Exit' which closes the application. Other buttons replace the window with a task-specific window. All the task Windows have a 'Close' button which returns to the Welcome screen. Conventionally, the Close button is in the same place as the Exit button in the Welcome window.

The problem I have is that some users are trigger happy and double click on the Close buttons. The first click triggers the Close action, and the task window closes. But it would appear that the second click is being bufferred, and is given to the Welcome window once it is displayed, and results in the Exit button being clicked. This is NOT the desired behaviour!

Is there any way I can discard the unwanted second click on the Close button? The task windows raise an AppletClosing event back to the Welcome window when they are closing, so it would be easy to do it in that handler - if I knew what to do.

Thanks for any help - much appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: In the `AppletClosing` handler you could flush mouse input from the Windows event queue, but that probably won't be enough (the second click could still come just after the queue is flushed). But if you want to try it, I can post how to do it.

Comment: Here's how to flush mouse messages from the input queue: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/08/flush-click-events-in-c/

Comment: How about disabling the exit button when a task window is opened? Then the main form checks, when the child form gets closed and starts a timer (approx. 750ms). When this timer elapsed, the timer is stopped and the close button enabled again.

Comment: Try this: (assume the *task Form* is named `Form2`) `this.ControlBox = false; var f2 = new Form2(); f2.Bounds = this.Bounds; f2.FormClosed += async (s, ev) => { await Task.Delay(250); this.ControlBox = true; }; f2.Show();`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'd implemented a 'disable the Exit button for a short time' solution, and it's good to know that's about the best solution there is!